# Como buscar en un arraylist con iterator y modificar un objeto

Tags: java

La duda que tengo es que creo una lista de objetos y despues quiero usar el metodo mover para modificar una nave que esta en el arraylist y me tira error en el if que compara adentro del while

```
public class FlotaEstelar implements InterFlota,Cloneable{
private ArrayList<Nave> lista;
private String nombre;


public FlotaEstelar(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.lista= new ArrayList<Nave>();
}

@Override
public void agregaNave(Nave nave) {
    this.lista.add(nave);
}

@Override
public void eliminaNave(Nave nave) {
    this.lista.remove(nave);
}

@Override
public Iterator<Nave> iterator() {
    return this.lista.iterator();
}

@Override
public Object clone() {
    // TODO Implement this method
    return null;
}

    @Override
public void mover(Nave nave, int x, int y) {
    int z=0;
    if (this.lista.contains(nave)){
        Iterator i=this.lista.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext() && z==0){
            if(i.next().equals(nave)){
                Nave cambiar = (Nave) i.next();
                cambiar.posicion.incrementarPos(x,y);
                z=1;
            }
            i.next();
        }    
    }
}
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException at
>   java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854) at
>   client.FlotaEstelar.mover(FlotaEstelar.java:64) at
>   client.prueba.main(prueba.java:17)

Comment: ¿Podrías postear el error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)
 at client.FlotaEstelar.mover(FlotaEstelar.java:64)
 at client.prueba.main(prueba.java:17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haces dos llamadas a i.next(), por ejemplo, pongamos que el arraylist tiene 2 objetos, Nave1 y Nave 2:

```
@Override
public void mover(Nave nave, int x, int y) {
int z=0;
if (this.lista.contains(nave)){
    Iterator i=this.lista.iterator();

    while(i.hasNext() && z==0){
        //Aquí se llama por primera vez a i.next, por tanto aqui es nave1
        if(i.next().equals(nave)){
            //Aqui se llama por segunda vez a i.next, es decir, aqui es nave2
            Nave cambiar = (Nave) i.next();
            cambiar.posicion.incrementarPos(x,y);
            z=1;
        }
        i.next();
    }    
}
}
```

Por tanto, en el bucle haz tan solo una sola llamada a i.next() y almacénala en una variable.

```
@Override
public void mover(Nave nave, int x, int y) {
int z=0;
if (this.lista.contains(nave)){
    Iterator i=this.lista.iterator();

    while(i.hasNext() && z==0){
        Nave naveNueva = i.next();
        if(naveNueva.equals(nave)){

            naveNueva.posicion.incrementarPos(x,y);
            z=1;
        }
    }    
}
}
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas poner que tipo de excepción te arroja, pero estoy viendo los siguientes errores:

```
  @Override
  public void mover(Nave nave, int x, int y) {
     int z=0;
     if (this.lista.contains(nave)){
         Iterator i=this.lista.iterator(); 
         while(i.hasNext() && z==0){
             if(i.next().equals(nave)){ //aquí estas avanzando el iterador
            Nave cambiar = (Nave) i.next(); //aquí lo estas volviendo a avanzar. La nave que te de, no va a ser la del equals
            cambiar.posicion.incrementarPos(x,y);
            z=1;
        }
        i.next(); //aquí lo estás volviendo avanzar.
    }    
}
```

}

Intenta de esta forma:

```
 @Override
 public void mover(Nave nave, int x, int y) {
    int z=0;
    if (this.lista.contains(nave)){
        Iterator i=this.lista.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext() && z==0){
           Nave naveIterada = i.next();
           if(naveItearda != null && naveIterada.equals(nave)){
              naveIterada.posicion.incrementarPos(x,y);
              z=1;
           }
           /// i.next(); <<este ya no lo requieres, ya iteraste 
        }    
    }
 }
```

Por otro lado los métodos públicos que tienes no estás validando que el parámetro Nave sea nulo. Yo agregaría en esos la validación:

```
  public void agregaNave(Nave nave) {
      if (nave == null) {throw new IllegalArgumentException()");
      //etc...
  }
```

Eso lo pondría para evitar que dentro de la lista de naves no haya nulos.

Saludos.